# How to retrieve JSON data using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell

I have this JSON. Trying to retrieve tactics array by using below code in PowerShell.

Why the actual output is weird even though tactics contains comma separated values, it is considering as one value with space separated values.

How to get the expected output?

**My JSON:**

```
  {
       "displayName": "travel with mailbox permission",
     "tactics": [
            "InitialAccess",
            "PrivilegeEscalation"
          ],
          "techniques": [
            "T1078",
            "T1548"
          ]
  }
```

**My code:**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
     # The resourceVariable which holds the resource details
    [string] $jsonvariable
    
)   
 $json = Get-AutomationVariable -Name $jsonvariable
 $jsonObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
            
         echo $jsonObject.tactics
```

**Output:**

```
 Expected o/p:
 InitialAccess,PrivilegeEscalation
            
 Actual O/p :
 InitialAccess PrivilegeEscalation
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75372186/edit) your question and create a valid [mcve]. In its current state it produces a (`Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.`) error. With regards to the issue, this is just how it is displayed, the actual object is probably just an array. Try `$json.tactics.GetType()`, `$json.tactics.count` or  `$json.tactics[0]`.

Comment: The sample code you've posted is not valid PowerShell. Is `$json` a string containing the json?

Comment: @iRon $json.tactics.count is coming as 1 eventhough it has 2 values

Comment: @Mathias I have placed this json in automation variable in powershell runbook and trying to retrieve that json

Comment: Edited my code in the above post

Comment: "*$json.tactics.count is coming as 1 eventhough it has 2 value*". For me it returns 2: `('{"displayName":"travel with mailbox permission","tactics":["InitialAccess","PrivilegeEscalation"],"techniques":["T1078","T1548"]}' |ConvertFrom-Json).tactics.Count`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$json.tactics -join ','
```

Powershell is outputting each value in the array separately, rather than as a comma-separated list.